# How to use sequence unpacking with a sequence of variable length?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sequence, variable-assignment

If I know the length of a list in advance, I can use sequence unpacking to assign variable the elements of the list thus:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

x, y, z = my_list
```

If I don't know the length of the list in advance, how can I assign variables to the elements of the list using sequence unpacking? If for argument's sake I don't care how the variables are named, can I first get the length of the list and then unpack to this amount of arbitrarily-named variables?

Comment: I understand the arbitrarily-named variables are not a good idea; I am merely interested in the proof-of-concept to begin with.

Comment: An arbitrary amount of variables sounds like a list

Comment: Depending on what version of Python you are using, you don't even need to know the size of my_list.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly **not** recommend but possible:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
for counter, value in enumerate(my_list):
    exec 'a{} = {}'.format(counter, value)
print a0, a1, a2
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

Or use Python 3:

```
>>> a, *rest = my_list
>>> a
1
>>> rest
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can force the length of the list to unpacking to the size you want like this

```
>>> my_list=range(10)
>>> a,b,c = my_list[:3]
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

if they are less you get a error, otherwise you take the 3 first elements

to the case of less elements you can do something like this

```
>>> my_list=[1,2]
>>> x,y,z=(my_list[:3] +[-1]*3)[:3]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
-1
>>>
```

have a list with default values that you concatenate to the sub-list of my_list and from the result you take what you need

Comment: Or for "fun" (and fewer temp `list`s and possible large `list` concatenations): `from itertools import chain, islice, repeat`, `x, y, z = islice(chain(my_list, repeat(None)), 3)`. Replace `None` in `repeat` with your choice of fallback value. Involves no intermediate `list`s at all, and generates no default data unless it needs to. Mind you, your approach is fine and practical (I up-voted), I just enjoy theoretically optimal solutions too. :-)

Comment: Probably not what the OP wants mind you, but the scenario you're solving is the only case where unpacking a variable length `list` might make sense. Unpacking a variable `list` to variable arguments with generated names is insane.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is that you should leave these elements in a list. This is what a list is for.

The wrong answer is to add local variables in a roundabout way. For Python 3:

```
ctr = 0
for value in my_list:
    __builtins__.locals()['my_list_{}'.format(ctr)] = value
    ctr += 1
```

If `my_list` has `n` items, this will create variables `my_list_0, my_list_1, ..., my_list_{n-1}`.

Please don't do this.